# Is it possible to add a file into the project through `dotnet` CLI command?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

.NET Core 2.1

I have two similar questions:

1. Is it possible to add a new or existing file into the project through the `dotnet` CLI command and set the necessary value for its `CopyLocal` property?
2. Is it possible to add the existing file into the project **as a link** through the `dotnet` CLI command and set the necessary value for its `CopyLocal` property?

I not found this info in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet?tabs=netcore2x).

Comment: There are no tags for files in the .csproj file in .net core.  The way .csproj works in .net core is any file in the same folder and sub folder is included in that project. For the same reason, you cannot link a file in windows, you will need to copy to the folder.